# How to update a column date of postgres to some days ahead

Tags: postgresql, postgres-12

Im using postgres as my database and I have a table that has a date column.
The current value in this column is 2021-04-1 17:19:08

I want to update this column's value and move the date 20 (or any other amount of days) ahead so the new value will be 2021-04-20 17:19:08

the reason Im not doing it manually its because I have too much rows to move ahead so I need a query for that, and I need to freedom to choose the amount of days ahead

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add days using `INTERVAL` -

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '20 days';
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Nikhil Patil I managed to create the next query:

```
select 'UPDATE itpserver.managed_incidents SET trigger_time = ''' || trigger_time || ''' where id = ' || id::text || ';'

from (

      select id, trigger_time + INTERVAL '120 days' trigger_time

      FROM itpserver.managed_incidents 

) a

where 1=1

group by id,trigger_time

order by id
```

this query created all the update queries I needed in order to update all the rows in my table. (the trigger_time is the date column).

after it created all the update queries I needed, I ran all of them at the same time as a sql script

Comment: There is no need to _generate_ those queries. You can directly update the table using `update itpserver.managed_incidents  set trigger_time = trigger_time + interval '120 days'` directly.

Comment: Yes you are right... I complicated it too much :(